# Blazor pdf File Read/View from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, view, blazor

I am currently building an application using Blazor with a SQl database. The application allows for a user to upload pdf files to the server.

I've been searching for a simple and efficient way to read/view the pdf files from the SQL server but can not seem to find anything relevant.

I would prefer not to use JavaScript like in : https://www.pdftron.com/blog/webviewer/add-webviewer-to-blazor/

Anyone got a solution to this? Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing the pdf files in a directory on the server or in the database? If they are on the server could this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-outside-of-web-root

Comment: I'm storing the files in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the pdf as a byte array and render that in iframe.
[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61328463/how-to-render-byte-array-knowing-its-content-type-using-blazor/61330788#comment108497661_61330788)
just the source of data is different. If you store the data as a BLOB in the SQL server you should able to grab the data and convert it to base64.

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure it out.